# Is it possible (and if so how) to repair this hole in polystyrene coving? Is it normal "wear and tear" or does it indicate a problem?

Tags: ceiling, plaster

*Background: the room was converted from an integral garage to a dining room some time in the 1980s, the rest of the house dates from the 1960s. I have artex and textured plasterwork everywhere...*

I've been doing some painting etc in this room and as part of the work I put masking tape on this polystyrene coving whilst painting the main part of the wall. Unfortunately I left the masking tape on longer than I should and it was on there a few weeks before being removed.

When I removed the tape, the surface of the coving has come away, leaving a gaping hole underneath!

The hole is currently about 3.5" in size, although I have felt around the sides of the flaking part, and it feels like more could flake off easily and make the hole bigger. It feels like there isn't much "substance" or "thickness" to the coving.

The continuous section of coving that it's part of, is about 18" in length.

Questions:

- Is this a normal degradation of polystyrene coving or does it indicate an underlying problem? (I haven't had any other "symptoms")
- Is it possible (and how) to go about repairing this, or do I need to remove and replace this section?

This is the hole as it looks currently:

[image: Picture 1]

This is what the inside looks like when I shine a light into it:

[image: Picture 2]

This is the stuff that "came out" of the hole when it disintegrated. I think it looks like just small pieces of polystyrene, but I've included it in case it indicates a problem of something else. (For some reason the bits look slightly green in the photo... they are actually white.)

[image: Picture 3]

**For now I've "repaired" it by sticking more masking tape over, as I could feel air from the outside coming through the hole.**

Comment: With the way the paint around that is bubbled, dripped and flaked I'd have guessed the house was from the _1860s_. Are you sure you don't want to just clean it all out and start fresh? Anything that thin and fragile doesn't seem worth the hassle of saving to me.

Comment: @isherwood I would love to rip all of it out and start fresh! At the moment I'm in the middle of renovations in the rest of the house (oddly, the main 1960s part has held up much better than the conversion!) so I'm ideally looking for a "minimal impact" way this can be repaired, unless it indicates something much more fundamentally wrong. Btw, the paint below it (on the wall rather than the coving) isn't bubbled, but for some reason it's done in a textured plasterwork finish...

Comment: I see. My guess is that the original cove material is so badly degraded that it has no strength. Not having experience with it, my approach would be to inject some low-expansion canned spray foam as a reinforcement and skim base.

Comment: I'd agree w/@isherwood. He should write that up as an _answer_. ;) TBH, though, I'm not sure that plastic cove had much "strength" to begin with - it was probably fairly fragile to begin with and has only gotten more brittle over time.